# How to deploy windows service on remote system using c# Programatically

Tags: c#, windows-services

I Created a windows service using c#, now from server system using remote system ip address i want to deploy this windows service using c# code. these client and server systems are under same network.Can anyone provide some sample codes how this can be achieved using c#.

using the below code i m trying to deploy windows service in remote meachine using remote Ip address from server. here i m getting error on
             `using (var scmHandle = NativeMethods.OpenSCManager(GetMachineNameFromIPAddress(IP), null, NativeMethods.SCM_ACCESS.SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE))` line.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var scmHandle = NativeMethods.OpenSCManager(GetMachineNameFromIPAddress(IP), null, NativeMethods.SCM_ACCESS.SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE))
            {
                if (scmHandle.IsInvalid)
                {
                    throw new Win32Exception();
                }

                using (
                    var serviceHandle = NativeMethods.CreateService(
                        scmHandle,
                        "ServiceName122",
                        "ServiceName122",
                        NativeMethods.SERVICE_ACCESS.SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,
                        NativeMethods.SERVICE_TYPES.SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
                        NativeMethods.SERVICE_START_TYPES.SERVICE_AUTO_START,
                        NativeMethods.SERVICE_ERROR_CONTROL.SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,
                        dir + "\\TestWindowService.exe",
                        null,
                        IntPtr.Zero,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null))
                {
                    if (serviceHandle.IsInvalid)
                    {
                        throw new Win32Exception();
                    }

                    NativeMethods.StartService(serviceHandle, 0, null);
                }
            }
        }




private static string GetMachineNameFromIPAddress(string ipAdress)
        {
            string machineName = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAdress);

                machineName = hostEntry.HostName;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Machine not found...
            }
            return machineName;
        }

public static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern ServiceControlHandle OpenSCManager(string lpMachineName, string lpSCDB, SCM_ACCESS scParameter);

        [DllImport("Advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern ServiceControlHandle CreateService(
            ServiceControlHandle serviceControlManagerHandle,
            string lpSvcName,
            string lpDisplayName,
            SERVICE_ACCESS dwDesiredAccess,
            SERVICE_TYPES dwServiceType,
            SERVICE_START_TYPES dwStartType,
            SERVICE_ERROR_CONTROL dwErrorControl,
            string lpPathName,
            string lpLoadOrderGroup,
            IntPtr lpdwTagId,
            string lpDependencies,
            string lpServiceStartName,
            string lpPassword);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool CloseServiceHandle(IntPtr serviceHandle);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool ControlService(IntPtr hService, SERVICE_CONTROL dwControl, ref SERVICE_STATUS lpServiceStatus);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern int StartService(ServiceControlHandle serviceHandle, int dwNumServiceArgs, string lpServiceArgVectors);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenService(ServiceControlHandle serviceControlManagerHandle, string lpSvcName, SERVICE_ACCESS dwDesiredAccess);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern int DeleteService(ServiceControlHandle serviceHandle);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetLastError();

        [Flags]
        public enum ACCESS_MASK : uint
        {
            DELETE = 0x00010000,

            READ_CONTROL = 0x00020000,

            WRITE_DAC = 0x00040000,

            WRITE_OWNER = 0x00080000,

            SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000,

            STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000,

            STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = 0x00020000,

            STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE = 0x00020000,

            STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE = 0x00020000,

            STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x001F0000,

            SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x0000FFFF,

            ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY = 0x01000000,

            MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 0x02000000,

            GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000,

            GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000,

            GENERIC_EXECUTE = 0x20000000,

            GENERIC_ALL = 0x10000000,

            DESKTOP_READOBJECTS = 0x00000001,

            DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW = 0x00000002,

            DESKTOP_CREATEMENU = 0x00000004,

            DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL = 0x00000008,

            DESKTOP_JOURNALRECORD = 0x00000010,

            DESKTOP_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 0x00000020,

            DESKTOP_ENUMERATE = 0x00000040,

            DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS = 0x00000080,

            DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP = 0x00000100,

            WINSTA_ENUMDESKTOPS = 0x00000001,

            WINSTA_READATTRIBUTES = 0x00000002,

            WINSTA_ACCESSCLIPBOARD = 0x00000004,

            WINSTA_CREATEDESKTOP = 0x00000008,

            WINSTA_WRITEATTRIBUTES = 0x00000010,

            WINSTA_ACCESSGLOBALATOMS = 0x00000020,

            WINSTA_EXITWINDOWS = 0x00000040,

            WINSTA_ENUMERATE = 0x00000100,

            WINSTA_READSCREEN = 0x00000200,

            WINSTA_ALL_ACCESS = 0x0000037F
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum SCM_ACCESS : uint
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Required to connect to the service control manager.
            /// </summary>
            SC_MANAGER_CONNECT = 0x00001,

            /// <summary>
            /// Required to call the CreateService function to create a service
            /// object and add it to the database.
            /// </summary>
            SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE = 0x00002,

            /// <summary>
            /// Required to call the EnumServicesStatusEx function to list the 
            /// services that are in the database.
            /// </summary>
            SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE = 0x00004,

            /// <summary>
            /// Required to call the LockServiceDatabase function to acquire a 
            /// lock on the database.
            /// </summary>
            SC_MANAGER_LOCK = 0x00008,

            /// <summary>
            /// Required to call the QueryServiceLockStatus function to retrieve 
            /// the lock status information for the database.
            /// </summary>
            SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS = 0x00010,

            /// <summary>
            /// Required to call the NotifyBootConfigStatus function.
            /// </summary>
            SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG = 0x00020,

            /// <summary>
            /// Includes STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED, in addition to all access 
            /// rights in this table.
            /// </summary>
            SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS =
                ACCESS_MASK.STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SC_MANAGER_CONNECT | SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE | SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE | SC_MANAGER_LOCK | SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS
                | SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG,

            GENERIC_READ = ACCESS_MASK.STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE | SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS,

            GENERIC_WRITE = ACCESS_MASK.STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE | SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE | SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG,

            GENERIC_EXECUTE = ACCESS_MASK.STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE | SC_MANAGER_CONNECT | SC_MANAGER_LOCK,

            GENERIC_ALL = SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS,
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum SERVICE_CONTROL : uint
        {
            STOP = 0x00000001,

            PAUSE = 0x00000002,

            CONTINUE = 0x00000003,

            INTERROGATE = 0x00000004,

            SHUTDOWN = 0x00000005,

            PARAMCHANGE = 0x00000006,

            NETBINDADD = 0x00000007,

            NETBINDREMOVE = 0x00000008,

            NETBINDENABLE = 0x00000009,

            NETBINDDISABLE = 0x0000000A,

            DEVICEEVENT = 0x0000000B,

            HARDWAREPROFILECHANGE = 0x0000000C,

            POWEREVENT = 0x0000000D,

            SESSIONCHANGE = 0x0000000E
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum SERVICE_ACCESS : uint
        {
            STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0xF0000,

            SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG = 0x00001,

            SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG = 0x00002,

            SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS = 0x00004,

            SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS = 0x00008,

            SERVICE_START = 0x00010,

            SERVICE_STOP = 0x00020,

            SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE = 0x00040,

            SERVICE_INTERROGATE = 0x00080,

            SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL = 0x00100,

            SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS =
                (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG | SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG | SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS | SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS | SERVICE_START | SERVICE_STOP | SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE
                 | SERVICE_INTERROGATE | SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL)
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum SERVICE_TYPES : int
        {
            SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER = 0x00000001,

            SERVICE_FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER = 0x00000002,

            SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS = 0x00000010,

            SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS = 0x00000020,

            SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS = 0x00000100
        }

        public enum SERVICE_ERROR_CONTROL : int
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The startup program logs the error in the event log, if possible. If the last-known-good configuration is being started, the startup operation fails. Otherwise, the system is restarted with the last-known good configuration.
            /// </summary>
            SERVICE_ERROR_CRITICAL = 0x00000003,

            /// <summary>
            /// The startup program ignores the error and continues the startup operation.
            /// </summary>
            SERVICE_ERROR_IGNORE = 0x00000000,

            /// <summary>
            /// The startup program logs the error in the event log but continues the startup operation.
            /// </summary>
            SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL = 0x00000001,

            /// <summary>
            /// The startup program logs the error in the event log. If the last-known-good configuration is being started, the startup operation continues. Otherwise, the system is restarted with the last-known-good configuration.
            /// </summary>
            SERVICE_ERROR_SEVERE = 0x00000002,
        }

        public enum SERVICE_START_TYPES : int
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// A service started automatically by the service control manager during system startup. For more information, see Automatically Starting Services.
            /// </summary>
            SERVICE_AUTO_START = 0x00000002,

            /// <summary>
            /// A device driver started by the system loader. This value is valid only for driver services.
            /// </summary>
            SERVICE_BOOT_START = 0x00000000,

            /// <summary>
            /// A service started by the service control manager when a process calls the StartService function. For more information, see Starting Services on Demand.
            /// </summary>
            SERVICE_DEMAND_START = 0x00000003,

            /// <summary>
            /// A service that cannot be started. Attempts to start the service result in the error code ERROR_SERVICE_DISABLED.
            /// </summary>
            SERVICE_DISABLED = 0x00000004,

            /// <summary>
            /// A device driver started by the IoInitSystem function. This value is valid only for driver services.
            /// </summary>
            SERVICE_SYSTEM_START = 0x00000001

        }

        public enum SERVICE_STATE : uint
        {
            SERVICE_STOPPED = 0x00000001,

            SERVICE_START_PENDING = 0x00000002,

            SERVICE_STOP_PENDING = 0x00000003,

            SERVICE_RUNNING = 0x00000004,

            SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING = 0x00000005,

            SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING = 0x00000006,

            SERVICE_PAUSED = 0x00000007
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public struct SERVICE_STATUS
        {
            public static readonly int SizeOf = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SERVICE_STATUS));

            public SERVICE_TYPES dwServiceType;

            public SERVICE_STATE dwCurrentState;

            public uint dwControlsAccepted;

            public uint dwWin32ExitCode;

            public uint dwServiceSpecificExitCode;

            public uint dwCheckPoint;

            public uint dwWaitHint;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Elaborate it more please.

Comment: @MurtazaKanchwala, I added code for reference and updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

1 year late, but I got this working when I tried out your code... I noticed I get a return of 5 (Access Denied) when calling

```
int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
```

This is probably because the process (visual studio) isn't running elevated (has a Medium integrity instead of High). Run VS elevated and see. To get any error being set, I had to modify your DllImport declaration of the OpenSCManager to add these attributes:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenSCManagerW", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(string lpMachineName, string lpSCDB, SCM_ACCESS scParameter);
```

Particularly the

```
SetLastError = true
```

You should declare your Windows APIs like he did here, mainly with SetLastError = true:

[How can Install a windows services with c# code i have using the Administrator privilege account I have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068907/how-can-install-a-windows-services-with-c-sharp-code-i-have-using-the-administra)

Note: I also changed ServiceControlHandle to IntPtr and simply do if (scmHandle == IntPtr.Zero) instead of .IsValid. IDK what ServiceControlHandle is.

Full code with some modifications I made. I put this in a basic Winform C# app, and on Form1_Shown just call that main method. Also handled scenario when service already exists.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RemoteSCMTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainMethod();
        }

        static void MainMethod()
        {
            // Current computer IP
            string remoteIpAddress = "192.168.2.110";

            string compName = GetMachineNameFromIPAddress(remoteIpAddress);
            var scmHandle = NativeMethods.OpenSCManager(compName, null, NativeMethods.SCM_ACCESS.SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE);

            if (scmHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(err);
            }



            string servicePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Security Assist\isa.exe";      // A path to some running service now
            string serviceName = "ServiceName122";
            string serviceDispName = "Service Display Name 122";

            IntPtr svcHandleCreated = IntPtr.Zero;
            int createdErr = 0;
            bool created = CreateService(scmHandle, servicePath, serviceName, serviceDispName, out svcHandleCreated, out createdErr);

            if (!created)
            {
                if(createdErr == 1073)
                {
                    // Error: "The specified service already exists"

                    IntPtr svcHandleOpened = NativeMethods.OpenService(scmHandle, serviceName, NativeMethods.SERVICE_ACCESS.SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);

                    if(svcHandleOpened != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        bool deletedService = NativeMethods.DeleteService(svcHandleOpened);
                        NativeMethods.CloseServiceHandle(svcHandleOpened);

                        if(deletedService)
                        {
                            // Try to create it again:
                            bool created2 = CreateService(scmHandle, servicePath, serviceName, serviceDispName, out svcHandleCreated, out createdErr);
                            if(!created2)
                            {
                                throw new Win32Exception(createdErr);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Service was successfully opened, but unable to delete the service
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Unable to open that service name w/ All Access
                        int openErr = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                        throw new Win32Exception(openErr);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    // Some other serice creation error than it already existing
                    throw new Win32Exception(createdErr);
                }

            }

            // Run!
            NativeMethods.StartService(svcHandleCreated, 0, null);

            // Cleanup
            NativeMethods.CloseServiceHandle(svcHandleCreated);
            NativeMethods.CloseServiceHandle(scmHandle);
        }

        static bool CreateService(IntPtr scmHandle, string servicePath, string serviceName, string serviceDispName, out IntPtr serviceHandleCreated, out int errorCodeIfFailed)
        {
            serviceHandleCreated = IntPtr.Zero;
            errorCodeIfFailed = 0;

            serviceHandleCreated = NativeMethods.CreateService(
                scmHandle,
                serviceName,
                serviceDispName,
                NativeMethods.SERVICE_ACCESS.SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,
                NativeMethods.SERVICE_TYPES.SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
                NativeMethods.SERVICE_START_TYPES.SERVICE_AUTO_START,
                NativeMethods.SERVICE_ERROR_CONTROL.SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,
                servicePath,
                null,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                null,
                null,
                null);

            if(serviceHandleCreated == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                errorCodeIfFailed = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }

            return serviceHandleCreated != IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        static string GetMachineNameFromIPAddress(string ipAdress)
        {
            string machineName = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAdress);

                machineName = hostEntry.HostName;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Machine not found...
            }
            return machineName;
        }

    } // Form1 Class


    #region Windows APIs (NativeMethods class)

    public static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32", EntryPoint = "OpenSCManagerW", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(string lpMachineName, string lpSCDB, SCM_ACCESS scParameter);

        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateService(
            IntPtr serviceControlManagerHandle,
            string lpSvcName,
            string lpDisplayName,
            SERVICE_ACCESS dwDesiredAccess,
            SERVICE_TYPES dwServiceType,
            SERVICE_START_TYPES dwStartType,
            SERVICE_ERROR_CONTROL dwErrorControl,
            string lpPathName,
            string lpLoadOrderGroup,
            IntPtr lpdwTagId,
            string lpDependencies,
            string lpServiceStartName,
            string lpPassword);

        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CloseServiceHandle(IntPtr serviceHandle);

        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool ControlService(IntPtr hService, SERVICE_CONTROL dwControl, ref SERVICE_STATUS lpServiceStatus);

        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int StartService(IntPtr serviceHandle, int dwNumServiceArgs, string lpServiceArgVectors);

        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenService(IntPtr serviceControlManagerHandle, string lpSvcName, SERVICE_ACCESS dwDesiredAccess);

        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool DeleteService(IntPtr serviceHandle);

        [Flags]
        public enum ACCESS_MASK : uint
        {
            DELETE = 0x00010000,

            READ_CONTROL = 0x00020000,

            WRITE_DAC = 0x00040000,

            WRITE_OWNER = 0x00080000,

            SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000,

            STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000,

            STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = 0x00020000,

            STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE = 0x00020000,

            STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE = 0x00020000,

            STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x001F0000,

            SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x0000FFFF,

            ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY = 0x01000000,

            MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 0x02000000,

            GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000,

            GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000,

            GENERIC_EXECUTE = 0x20000000,

            GENERIC_ALL = 0x10000000,

            DESKTOP_READOBJECTS = 0x00000001,

            DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW = 0x00000002,

            DESKTOP_CREATEMENU = 0x00000004,

            DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL = 0x00000008,

            DESKTOP_JOURNALRECORD = 0x00000010,

            DESKTOP_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 0x00000020,

            DESKTOP_ENUMERATE = 0x00000040,

            DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS = 0x00000080,

            DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP = 0x00000100,

            WINSTA_ENUMDESKTOPS = 0x00000001,

            WINSTA_READATTRIBUTES = 0x00000002,

            WINSTA_ACCESSCLIPBOARD = 0x00000004,

            WINSTA_CREATEDESKTOP = 0x00000008,

            WINSTA_WRITEATTRIBUTES = 0x00000010,

            WINSTA_ACCESSGLOBALATOMS = 0x00000020,

            WINSTA_EXITWINDOWS = 0x00000040,

            WINSTA_ENUMERATE = 0x00000100,

            WINSTA_READSCREEN = 0x00000200,

            WINSTA_ALL_ACCESS = 0x0000037F
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum SCM_ACCESS : uint
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Required to connect to the service control manager.
            /// </summary>
            SC_MANAGER_CONNECT = 0x00001,

            /// <summary>
            /// Required to call the CreateService function to create a service
            /// object and add it to the database.
            /// </summary>
            SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE = 0x00002,

            /// <summary>
            /// Required to call the EnumServicesStatusEx function to list the 
            /// services that are in the database.
            /// </summary>
            SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE = 0x00004,

            /// <summary>
            /// Required to call the LockServiceDatabase function to acquire a 
            /// lock on the database.
            /// </summary>
            SC_MANAGER_LOCK = 0x00008,

            /// <summary>
            /// Required to call the QueryServiceLockStatus function to retrieve 
            /// the lock status information for the database.
            /// </summary>
            SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS = 0x00010,

            /// <summary>
            /// Required to call the NotifyBootConfigStatus function.
            /// </summary>
            SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG = 0x00020,

            /// <summary>
            /// Includes STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED, in addition to all access 
            /// rights in this table.
            /// </summary>
            SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS =
                ACCESS_MASK.STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SC_MANAGER_CONNECT | SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE | SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE | SC_MANAGER_LOCK | SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS
                | SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG,

            GENERIC_READ = ACCESS_MASK.STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE | SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS,

            GENERIC_WRITE = ACCESS_MASK.STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE | SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE | SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG,

            GENERIC_EXECUTE = ACCESS_MASK.STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE | SC_MANAGER_CONNECT | SC_MANAGER_LOCK,

            GENERIC_ALL = SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS,
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum SERVICE_CONTROL : uint
        {
            STOP = 0x00000001,

            PAUSE = 0x00000002,

            CONTINUE = 0x00000003,

            INTERROGATE = 0x00000004,

            SHUTDOWN = 0x00000005,

            PARAMCHANGE = 0x00000006,

            NETBINDADD = 0x00000007,

            NETBINDREMOVE = 0x00000008,

            NETBINDENABLE = 0x00000009,

            NETBINDDISABLE = 0x0000000A,

            DEVICEEVENT = 0x0000000B,

            HARDWAREPROFILECHANGE = 0x0000000C,

            POWEREVENT = 0x0000000D,

            SESSIONCHANGE = 0x0000000E
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum SERVICE_ACCESS : uint
        {
            STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0xF0000,

            SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG = 0x00001,

            SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG = 0x00002,

            SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS = 0x00004,

            SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS = 0x00008,

            SERVICE_START = 0x00010,

            SERVICE_STOP = 0x00020,

            SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE = 0x00040,

            SERVICE_INTERROGATE = 0x00080,

            SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL = 0x00100,

            SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS =
                (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG | SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG | SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS | SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS | SERVICE_START | SERVICE_STOP | SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE
                    | SERVICE_INTERROGATE | SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL)
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum SERVICE_TYPES : int
        {
            SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER = 0x00000001,

            SERVICE_FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER = 0x00000002,

            SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS = 0x00000010,

            SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS = 0x00000020,

            SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS = 0x00000100
        }

        public enum SERVICE_ERROR_CONTROL : int
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The startup program logs the error in the event log, if possible. If the last-known-good configuration is being started, the startup operation fails. Otherwise, the system is restarted with the last-known good configuration.
            /// </summary>
            SERVICE_ERROR_CRITICAL = 0x00000003,

            /// <summary>
            /// The startup program ignores the error and continues the startup operation.
            /// </summary>
            SERVICE_ERROR_IGNORE = 0x00000000,

            /// <summary>
            /// The startup program logs the error in the event log but continues the startup operation.
            /// </summary>
            SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL = 0x00000001,

            /// <summary>
            /// The startup program logs the error in the event log. If the last-known-good configuration is being started, the startup operation continues. Otherwise, the system is restarted with the last-known-good configuration.
            /// </summary>
            SERVICE_ERROR_SEVERE = 0x00000002,
        }

        public enum SERVICE_START_TYPES : int
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// A service started automatically by the service control manager during system startup. For more information, see Automatically Starting Services.
            /// </summary>
            SERVICE_AUTO_START = 0x00000002,

            /// <summary>
            /// A device driver started by the system loader. This value is valid only for driver services.
            /// </summary>
            SERVICE_BOOT_START = 0x00000000,

            /// <summary>
            /// A service started by the service control manager when a process calls the StartService function. For more information, see Starting Services on Demand.
            /// </summary>
            SERVICE_DEMAND_START = 0x00000003,

            /// <summary>
            /// A service that cannot be started. Attempts to start the service result in the error code ERROR_SERVICE_DISABLED.
            /// </summary>
            SERVICE_DISABLED = 0x00000004,

            /// <summary>
            /// A device driver started by the IoInitSystem function. This value is valid only for driver services.
            /// </summary>
            SERVICE_SYSTEM_START = 0x00000001

        }

        public enum SERVICE_STATE : uint
        {
            SERVICE_STOPPED = 0x00000001,

            SERVICE_START_PENDING = 0x00000002,

            SERVICE_STOP_PENDING = 0x00000003,

            SERVICE_RUNNING = 0x00000004,

            SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING = 0x00000005,

            SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING = 0x00000006,

            SERVICE_PAUSED = 0x00000007
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public struct SERVICE_STATUS
        {
            public static readonly int SizeOf = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SERVICE_STATUS));

            public SERVICE_TYPES dwServiceType;

            public SERVICE_STATE dwCurrentState;

            public uint dwControlsAccepted;

            public uint dwWin32ExitCode;

            public uint dwServiceSpecificExitCode;

            public uint dwCheckPoint;

            public uint dwWaitHint;
        }

    } // NativeMethods class

    #endregion
}
```